# Server side UI vs. Client side UI

Tags: job-description

I'm reading a job description which reads...

> You are an experienced front-end developer with expertise in Javascript,HTML,CSS & server side UI frameworks (PHP/Python/Node.js).

I've always felt that it's best to render on the client side so I use AngularJS for this. Not PHP/Python/Node.js.  This makes me wonder if the job description is wrong; server-side UI doesn't sound right to me.

Should I ask them about it or just apply anyway?  If I apply and get an interview, should I try to explain why that approach doesn't sound right?

Comment: I think it could fit here if it could be made more generic, though I think the author is asking the wrong question (which I've explained in my answer). When considering the underlying issue, it's quite a bit more on topic for this site (which I've addressed in my answer).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about job functions and not about navigating the workplace as described in the [help]

Comment: I'm not arguing that it isn't offtopic as it's currently worded. If the asker did actually intend to ask about front end languages vs backend languages, then there's no question that it's better suited to programmers.SE. However, if it's more about the job description vs actual duties, then I think that it can fit here **if reworded**.

Comment: @fauverism I made an edit to your question to try to make it fit The Workplace better.  You might ask your question about client-side versus server-side approaches elsewhere on Stack Exchange (maybe Programmers).  I focused this question on the job description and application process.  If I've failed to capture your intentions or put too many words in your mouth you can [edit] further.  Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply put -- **most companies suck at writing job postings.** (Also, I think you're asking the wrong question, given you've posted the question on workplace.SE, as opposed to programmers.SE.)

The sad truth is that a large portion of companies run their job postings through just about everyone but the people that actually know how to do the job (this is especially the case for highly skilled positions). The group needing the person might send their requirements to HR, then HR writes the actual job description for the posting. As a result, you end up with things like requiring server side technologies for front end devs or designers, more years of experience than a technology has been around, "entry level" positions that require ludicrous amounts of knowledge, and other such oddities.

This example job description isn't about whether one should use Node to render client side UI (by the way, it would all ultimately get converted to HTML, anyway), but rather whether what they *say* they want is what they *actually need*. It says nothing about whether their requirement of a front end developer needing to know server side languages is actually an accurate or reasonable expectation.

Personally, I ignore such job postings entirely unless I have internal contacts. Odds are, your resume will go through HR's game of buzzword bingo and get tossed before it ever sees anyone who actually knows anything about the job, and if it does make it through, the odds are higher that it won't be a good match than a job with a more reasonable/accurate posting.